# How to override the response body of AuthenticationFailure using AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-security

I'm using a Custom Filter to make the request Authetincation. Configuring the `AutheticationFailureHandler`, I want put the message error content, but it is attached to a existent default content, my goal is put together on the same body or just a new one.

Handler impl.:

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
APIKeyAuthFilter apiKeyAuthFilter = new APIKeyAuthFilter(HEADER_USER_AGENT, HEADER_APIKEY);

apiKeyAuthFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                if(exception.getMessage().equals(MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND)) {
                    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("message",MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND);
                    response.getOutputStream()
                            .println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
                }
            });
}
```

Response body:

```
{
    "message": "User-Agent not found."
}
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-16T16:26:59.438+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/api"
}
```

Like shows, this is returning two JSON contents. How I set just one or append to existent?

Whole code:

```
public class APIKeyAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    private String userAgentRequestHeader;
    private String apiKeyRequestHeader;

    public APIKeyAuthFilter(String userAgentRequestHeader, String apiKeyRequestHeader) {
        this.userAgentRequestHeader = userAgentRequestHeader;
        this.apiKeyRequestHeader = apiKeyRequestHeader;
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestAuthVo getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader(userAgentRequestHeader);
        String apiKey = request.getHeader(apiKeyRequestHeader);
        RequestAuthVo requestAuthVo = new RequestAuthVo(userAgent,apiKey);
        return requestAuthVo;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "N/A";
    }

}
```

Configure:

```
        @Override
        @Order(2)
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
                APIKeyAuthFilter apiKeyAuthFilter = new APIKeyAuthFilter(HEADER_USER_AGENT, HEADER_APIKEY);

            apiKeyAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
                RequestAuthVo requestAuthVo = (RequestAuthVo) authentication.getPrincipal();

                if (!mapAuths.containsKey(requestAuthVo.getUserAgent())) {
                    throw new UserAgentNotFoundException(MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND);
                }

                if(mapAuths.containsKey(requestAuthVo.getUserAgent()) && mapAuths.get(requestAuthVo.getUserAgent()).equals(requestAuthVo.getApiKey())) {
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                    return authentication;
                }

                return authentication;
            });

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

 apiKeyAuthFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                    if(exception.getMessage().equals(MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND)) {
                        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                        data.put("message",MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND);
                        response.getOutputStream()
                                .println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
                    }
                });

            httpSecurity.antMatcher("/**").
                    csrf().disable().
                    sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
                    and()
                    .addFilter(apiKeyAuthFilter).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you replace `response.getOutputStream().println`  with `response.sendError(403, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data))` and see ? And also can you add the rest of `configure` to see where your `APIKeyAuthFilter` is plugged in?

Comment: with `response.sendError(403, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data))`. The response body is just: `1`.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I've edited with `configure` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
    apiKeyAuthFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(
            (request, response, exception) -> {
        if(exception.getMessage().equals(MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND)) {
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("message",MESSAGE_USER_AGENT_NOT_FOUND);
            request.setAttribute("AGENT_NOT_FOUND", 
                                 objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
        }
    });

    http.exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, e) ->
      {
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        String value = request.getAttribute("AGENT_NOT_FOUND").toString();
        response.getWriter().write(value);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Worked. But this approach is a little verbose.